# Extend $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^n +z^{n-1}+...+z^2 + z^{-n}}+\frac{c}{z-1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, analytic-continuation

find $c $ such that    $ f(z)=\frac{1}{z^n +z^{n-1}+...+z^2 + z^{-n}}+\frac{c}{z-1}$ can be extended to be analytic at $z=1$ , when $n\in \mathbb{N}$ when  $n$ is fixed.

The given function I write it as $f(z)=\frac{z^n(z-1)+c(z^n+1)(z^{n+1} -1) }{(z-1)(z^n +1) (z^{n+1} + 1)}$

Further i tried to evaluate limit at 1, so that I can choose c , so that my limit will always exist...

I dont know my approach is false.. Help me please

Comment: Are you familiar with Riemann's theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity?

Comment: No. It is the first time i am encounter with such problem.. Let me check what is it about.

Comment: Actually, it is not clear how your $f$ is defined. There is an unexpected $z^2$ in the denominator of the first term of $f$. If that is what you intended, you need to give a more explicit description of $f$.

Comment: This is an assignment question...!! No changes

Comment: It doesn't matter, the form of $f$ as you have it above is undefined. What is the term immediate;y preceding $z^2$ in the denominator?

Comment: $c=0$ as the big fraction term is obviously analytic at $1$

Comment: the term immediately preceding $z^2$ is $z^{-n}$

Comment: That makes no sense.

Comment: why doesnt that make no sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Surely $f(x)$ is analytic at a small enough neiborhood of $z=1$, therefore $z=1$ is an isolated singularity of $f(x)$ **for all values of $c$ EXCEPT ONE** for which:$$\lim_{z\to 1}(z-1)f(z)=0$$Now what's the value of $c$?